# is it possible that python .add_driver command cant create f-curve?

Tags: python, rigging, drivers

If I created a constraint on some bone, in pose mode - let's say Copy Location. And then manually created a driver on the influence (right mouse button > Add Driver), the f-curve with 2 points was created. No problem

[image]

But after the same operation, on the same bone  and property, but with python command `bpy.data.objects["Armature"].pose.bones["some_bone"].constraints["Copy Location"].driver_add("influence")`
the f-curve wasn't created, do I miss something?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, with the python command `.add_driver` the generator modifier is automatically generated (m.f.!).

[image]

If you want rid of it, you can use

```
mod = bpy.data.objects["Armature"].animation_data.drivers[0].modifiers[0]
bpy.data.objects["Armature"].animation_data.drivers[0].modifiers.remove(mod)
```